# Position a widget, inside a stack, but according to the center of the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to position a widget, `CustomWidget`, but at the specified position, i.e, top, left values, in the `Positioned` widget, I want there to be the center of my `CustomWidget`, instead of the top-left corner of my `CustomWidget`.

I want something like this:-

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Positioned(
      left: x,
      top: y,
      alignment: Alignment.center, //Alignment of the child widget, such that at (x, y) there is the center of the widget.
      child: CustomWidget(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Here is the type of UI I am trying to make, I am trying to make both cases:-
[image]

`CustomWidget` does not have any specific type, I am currently trying to make a general method, It might be a simple `Text` Widget with some variable value, or maybe a Widget with a `Row` of `Image`, `Divider` and `Text`.
I am basically using `CustomWidget` as a kind of popup, which will be used in case of some extra information, and also as a stamp over a widget, wherever the user clicks, in both cases, I cannot be certain of the size.

Note:- I do want to position the `CustomWidget` at a specified offset in the stack, but want that there should be the center of the `CustomWidget` instead of the top-left corner of `CustomWidget`.

Comment: could you please add some code too?

Comment: could you please add the ui you want to achive?

Comment: Yes, @eamirho3ein you are right.

Comment: @Vishnubly I need a UI screenshot to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: does CustomWidget have specific size? if not could you please add its class too?

Comment: @eamirho3ein `CustomWidget` does not have any particular size, currently, it might be any widget, I am planning to use it as a "stamp" over a widget and as a custom popup, which would appear on hovering at a widget.

Comment: use `Positioned` with `left` and `top` and `Align` as a child

Comment: @pskink your mentioned method does not work.

Comment: hmm, yes indeed, positioned + align doesn't work, but positioned + fractional translation do works, try `Offset(-0.5, -0.5)` for example, I am not sure though if this is a good solution (I mean if there is better widget for that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed a [package](https://pub.dev/packages/helpful_components), with many helpful components (basically the components, which I use often, in all my projects, so to prevent writing the same thing everywhere ). So there I have added this new `Widget` named [PositionedAlign](https://pub.dev/documentation/helpful_components/latest/positioned_align/PositionedAlign-class.html) this work according to the above question. I hope this helps anyone who might need it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget. Try using the [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget, remember to add `alignment: Alignment.center,` to center it.

Comment: I do want to position the `CustomWidget`, but just want that at the specified position there should be the center of the `CustomWidget`.

Comment: I have updated the question, with a screenshot of the kind of UI I am looking for.